# Will Ubuntu run on a System with ASUS P8Z77-V DELUXE Motherboard

Tags: kernel, hardware

Will Ubuntu (with latest stable kernel from source if neccessary) run on a System with ASUS P8Z77-V DELUXE Motherboard?

I could not find any hints by asus itself, but from the [debian hardware database](http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/ASUS) there are similar P8 motherboards with Z77 Chipset in the list.

Can anyone confirm that the other devices on the board are supported too?

Comment: Define "latest" kernel?.

Comment: @UriHerrera I want to run Ubuntu on the system, and if necessary I build a kernel from source for it. The latest kernel can be found on kernel.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it worked. I switched to gentoo in the meantime, but the kernel 3.6.11 supports all features of the motherboard (at least I did not miss any yet).

The lines `Kernel driver in use:` show which kernelmodules I used for this board.

```
# lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 84ca
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 841a
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev c4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 84ca
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8H77-I Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
04:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
06:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9120 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 12)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 83ba
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
07:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8488
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to run it from the install DVD, don't install it but run Ubuntu directly from the DVD and see if it works. I can't guarantee thought that there won't be a difference between running from the DVD or installed from an HDD/SSD. I have a similar board P8Z77-V Pro and it runs great from the DVD, haven't installed Ubuntu on this machine yet though.